# How do you set cursor on a ToolStripItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstripitem

I have some context menu items that are not clickable.  They just report the status of something.  I don't like how the cursor still appears like they're clickable though.

Anyway to change this?

There isn't a Cursor Field like one would expect.

Comment: There should be an option to set the mouse icon

Comment: @JohnnBlade Not on the ToolStripItem's themselves... but there is on the ContextMenuStrip.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the MouseMove event of the whole ToolStrip and check if the current mouse location is between the toolStripItem.Bounds. if so, change ToolStrip.Cursor

Comment: thanks for the reply.  You pointed me in the right direction.  FYI, MouseMove event isn't triggered when you are over the ToolStripMenuItems.  Only way to trigger it is was to put my cursor right on the edge of the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Amiram sent me in the right direction.  You can't set the Cursor on the "ToolStripMenuItem" you have to set it on the parent ContextMenuStrip.

As for the mouse events, that has to go on the ToolStripMenuItems.  As the MouseMove event is not fired when the Mouse is over ToolStripMenuItems.

```
    // Init Code
    contextMenuStrip1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    recentMessagesToolStripMenuItem.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(SetCursorToHandOn_MouseLeave);
    recentMessagesToolStripMenuItem.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(SetCursorToArrowOn_MouseEnter);


    private void SetCursorToArrowOn_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contextMenuStrip1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    private void SetCursorToHandOn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contextMenuStrip1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }
```